Three-player Avalon (transmitting private knowledge over a public channel)
Players

There are total three players split in two teams
Team Resistance has two players whose roles are assigned at the start of the game
Team Spy has one player

Before starting the game

Both resistance players must agree what Strategy they will follow during the game. The spy must be made aware of this Strategy. Both resistance players cannot deviate from this Strategy during the game.
The Spy does not need to reveal their strategy as a spy.

At the start of the game

Roles

One of the resistance players is assigned role Merlin and the other resistance player is assigned role Vanilla. Both possibilities are 50% probability each.
Merlin knows who is Vanilla and who is Spy. Vanilla knows who is Merlin and who is Spy. Spy does not know who is Merlin and who is Vanilla.


Secret

A variable called Secret is generated. Secret is 0 with 50% probability and 1 with 50% probability
Merlin knows the Secret. Spy know the Secret. Vanilla does not know the Secret.



During the game

There is a blackboard in public view of all players
The blackboard starts empty.
Merlin and Vanilla can write on the blackboard as per rules below. Spy can observe the blackboard but cannot write on it.
On timestep T, both Resistance players simultaneously write a "word" each on the blackboard, or they can write STOP. Neither player can see what the other player is writing during a timestep until both players finish writing their respective "word"s for a given timestep.
This "word" can depend on the state of the blackboard state until (and including) timestep T-1, and the role who is writing it.
A "word" can including English words, numbers or other characters.
Both players are allowed to generate random numbers in their head as part of their Strategy.
Neither player is not allowed to write down encryption keys on the whiteboard.

Ending the game

If a player writes STOP, this player must make a guess of what Secret is. If both players write STOP on the same timestep, one player is picked at random (50% probability each) and is asked to make a guess of what Secret is.
If this guess is incorrect, the Resistance team loses.
If this guess is correct, Spy must guess which of the Resistance players is Merlin.
If the Spy guesses correctly, the Resistance team loses. Else the Resistance team wins.

Assuming optimal play by the Spy, suggest a strategy that maximises expected probability of the Resistance team winning.

Of course if the spy knows the strategy, the spy also knows how to break the encryption keys.
